# Bash script copying certain type of file to another location

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I was thinking if using a BASH script is possible without manually copying each file that is in this parent directory

```
 "/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks"
```

So in this folder `PrivateFrameworks`, there are many subfolders and in each subfolder it consists of the file that I would like to copy it out to another location. So the structure of the path looks like this:

```
-PrivateFrameworks  
     -AccessibilityUI.framework 
        -AccessibilityUI <- copy this
     -AccountSettings.framework
        -AccountSettings <- copy this
```

I do not want the option of copying the entire content in the folder as there might be cases where the folders contain files which I do not want to copy. So the only way I thought of is to copy by the file extension. However as you can see, the files which I specified for copying does not have an extension(I think?). I am new to bash scripting so I am not familiar if this can be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy all files in or below the current directory that do not have extensions, use:

```
find . ! -name '*.*' -exec cp -t /your/destination/dir/ {} +
```

The `find .`  command looks for all files in or below the current directory.  The argument `-name '*.*'` would restrict that search to files that have extensions.  By preceding it with a not (`!`), however, we get all files that do *not* have an extension.  Then, `-exec cp -t /your/destination/dir/ {} +` tells find to copy those files to the destination.

To do the above starting in your directory with the long name, use:

```
find "/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks" ! -name '*.*' -exec cp -t /your/destination/dir/ {} +
```

**UPDATE**: The unix tag on this question has been removed and replaced with a OSX tag.  That means we can't use the `-t` option on `cp`.  The workaround is:

```
find . ! -name '*.*' -exec cp {} /your/destination/dir/ \;
```

This is less efficient because a new `cp` process is created for every file moved instead of once for all the files that fit on a command line.  But, it will accomplish the same thing.

**MORE:**  There are two variations of the `-exec` clause of a `find` command.  In the first use above, the clause ended with `{} +` which tells `find` to fill up the end of command line with as many file names as will fit on the line.

Since OSX lacks `cp -t`, however, we have to put the file name in the middle of the command.  So, we put `{}` where we want the file name and then, to signal to `find` where the end of the exec command is, we add a semicolon.  There is a trick, though.  Because bash would normally consume the semicolon itself rather than pass it on to `find`, we have to escape the semicolon with a backslash.  That way bash gives it to the find command.

Comment: hi thanks for your help. But apparently I have the illegal option when i use -t

Comment: @user2541163  OK.  Macs don't have `cp -t`.  See updated answer for workaround.

Comment: Hi really appreciate your help here. It works for me :). the explanation also helped me to understand better. Just 1 more question,  what is the difference with cp {} and  and i notice that the end has been replaced by a '\'

Comment: @user2541163 I added the explanation for the `\;`.

Comment: hi, just coming back to ask, is there a way to copy the files along with the parent directories they are in?

Comment: @user2541163 My first thought on that rsync is excellent at copying while preserving directory structure and, with a careful combination of --include and --exclude options, it would be what you want.  As a starting point, try `rsync -av --include='*/' --exclude='*.*' your_source your_destination`.  This includes all directories (`--include='*/'`) but excludes all regular files with extensions (`--exclude='*.*'`).  The order in which ---include and --exclude are specified is very important.

Comment: `find . ! -name '*.*' -exec class-dump-z -H {} -o /your/destination/dir/ \;` I think u can understand that from this im trying to dump my files and create header files with the -H option. how should i accomplish this with the line of code u just wrote

Comment: The rsync command was to be used in place of, not as part of, the find command.  I am not familiar with class-dump-z.

Comment: because by using this line of code, I will be able to get all the header files in 1 directory, but the problem is that there are 6000+ over of these header files and they are not categorized according to their parent folders

Answer (score 0):

`sh SCRIPT.sh copy-from-directory .extension copy-to-directory`

```
FROM_DIR=$1
EXTENSION=$2
TO_DIR=$3

USAGE="""Usage: sh SCRIPT.sh copy-from-directory .extension copy-to-directory

- EXAMPLE: sh SCRIPT.sh PrivateFrameworks .framework .
- NOTE: 'copy-to-directory' argument is optional
"""

## print usage if less than 2 args
if [[ $# < 2 ]]; then echo "${USAGE}" && exit 1 ; fi

## set copy-to-dir default args
if [[ -z "$TO_DIR" ]] ; then TO_DIR=$PWD ; fi

## DO SOMETHING...
## find directories; find target file; 
## copy target file to copy-to-dir if file exist
find $FROM_DIR -type d | while read DIR ; do
    FILE_TO_COPY=$(echo $DIR | xargs basename | sed "s/$EXTENSION//")

    if [[ -f $DIR/$FILE_TO_COPY ]] ; then
        cp $DIR/$FILE_TO_COPY $TO_DIR
    fi
done
```